# Fastest filtering method for very large DB (250M rows)

Tags: python, database, filter, dask

I'm reaching out because I need some advice on how to efficiently filter a very large database.

My database is composed of ~250M rows & 15 columns (I'm planning to expand it to 20 cols by the way). The whole thing is stored in a csv file for now.

```
         ID_bis                  ID      Table  ... call      prob  opp
0       211415746  turn288549796698g2    13h3d9h  ...  0.0  0.886725  0.0
1       211415747  turn288549796698g2    13h3d9h  ...  0.0  0.807899  0.0
2       211415748  turn288549796698g2    13h3d9h  ...  0.0  0.882484  0.0
3       211415752  turn288549796698g2    13h3d9h  ...  0.0  1.000000  0.0
4       211415753  turn288549796698g2    13h3d9h  ...  0.0  0.999563  0.0
          ...                 ...        ...  ...  ...       ...  ...
273412  238167402  turn673522979114g2  13h12s10c  ...  0.0  0.425253  0.0
273413  238167404  turn673522979114g2  13h12s10c  ...  0.0  0.102116  0.0
273414  238167405  turn673522979114g2  13h12s10c  ...  0.0  0.033802  0.0
273415  238167406  turn673522979114g2  13h12s10c  ...  0.0  0.496185  0.0
273416  238167407  turn673522979114g2  13h12s10c  ...  0.0  0.135174  0.0
```

I'd like to apply some filters to this dataframe & retrieve values. I was hoping to be able to do so using dask. Nevertheless, the processing time is very long (>60secs) while my goal is to filter & retrieve the value in <1sec.

Below is an example of filter

```
from dask import dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(path, sep=",")

df = df[(df["prob"] > 0.99) 
        & (df["actions_preflop"] == "re")
        & (df["actions_flop"] == "re")
        & (df["actions_turn"] == "-")
        & (df["actions_river"] == "-")
        & (df["Table"] == "14s13s10h")
        ]

df = df.compute()

raise_std = df["raise"].values
call_std = df["call"].values
```

At this point, what would be your recommendation to reach this 1sec filter target?

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How are you measuring time? Based on the code snippet you posted I would assume loading the 250M line csv might take quite a good chuck of 60s. How long is `df.compute` really taking?

Comment: The 60 secs was just a vague estimate to highlight the performance gap between my target (1 sec) and what actually happens.
Just did a test using “time()” on a 70M sub db, total time is 59secs. Opening the df is almost instantaneous, same for retrieving .values. >99% of the processing time comes from “compute”.
Note that the filtered dataframe was only 240 rows btw

Comment: I'm not sure what `pandas` does on the backend but I would first attempt a pure `numpy` implementation by converting fields to numeric values (i.e. encode classes raise-> 0, reraise->1, ...) and seeing then remeasuring the performance. // Another option may be to split up the DB based on the highest level actions. Have a preflop actions DB, then a flop actions, etc. Then switch between those per action type.

Comment: Ok I understand. Yes I could create DB for each stage of the game (but like I said above, even with a sub DB of 80M rows, the latency is still gigantic).

To your point about numpy: Should I actually consider convert the whole DB into a binary file instead? Sounds similar to what you suggested with numpy except that the conversion will already be done

Comment: Could you add more inputs: how much volume is the csv file(s) on disk? Why did you use Dask instead of Pandas in the first place?
Some other thoughts: CSV file format is really ineficient, you might want to try Parquet. Although ultimately, retrieving values in less than a second would probably need a real database like Postgres or NoSQL alternatives. A database is made for subsecond latency, not CSV files.

Comment: The 80M file that took 59 secondes is 7.4 gb for instance. I use dask as panda is much slower & not built to handle such large datasets

I understand about the DB, I'll see if I can make a try even though I don't have much experience Nosql topics